# Best pattern to call AWS API from Elm SPA?

Tags: single-page-application, aws-api-gateway, elm

I'm developing an application following quite closely [Feldman Elm SPA example](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example) with the API hosted on AWS API Gateway. My problem is the following:

I need to sign my API calls with [AWS API Signature v4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html). It is a less trivial task than I initially thought in Elm:

- There is no Elm AWS signature package, so I naturally looked at JS libraries to use via Ports.
- Option 1: Use [AWS Amplify API](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/api_guide) that does all the job => But then how to process the result in the most Elm-esque way (ideally with [RemoteData](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/ohanhi/remotedata-http/latest/)).
- Option 2: Use a third-party JS library just to sign the request forged by Elm [Http.request](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#request) and send send/process the HTTP request via Elm => So far I found only buggy implementations of AWS Sigv4, I would prefer an official implementation anyway.
- In the 2 cases, I'm stuck with the Main Parent / Page Children communication: I can send the request 1) or 2) via Port from the Child. But then, how to can the Child receive the response to his request? Indeed, all responses go into Elm via the same port subscription. Do I need to 'tag' the outgoing requests and then dispatch the response based on the tag? But it will look horrible and won't scale well.

Please note that it is a question about App pattern and architecture. It is not a basic question about Elm Ports (I already successfully call the API from Elm).

Any recommendations or pointers appreciated. Thanks!

### Additional info about my setup (following the first comment)

I follow the [AWS best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html#scenario-api-gateway) (scenario #3 *Access Resources with API Gateway and Lambda with a User Pool*)

- Front-end App users are managed by:

  - Cognito User Pool (signup, sign-in, etc...)
  - Cognito Identity Pool (map users with IAM role to access AWS resources, including the API Gateway)
- Back-end is Serverless: API Gateway + Lambda functions
- API Gateway: Lambda proxy integration + Authorization = IAM => this requires the AWS Signature
- I don't use API keys because:

  - I don't want to provide any access to the back-end to unauthenticated users
  - I need to identify the user from the request headers
  - I don't want to rely on long-term secrets for authentication on client side

Comment: I only have experience of communicating with the AWS API via a backend service for my client code, which means AWS keys are secure or the backend is running in an environment that inherits IAM Roles etc. Can you expand your question a little to explain how the JS options you found securely communicate with AWS from code running in the browser? Am I right in thinking the AWS Amplify API service you linked to sets up a backend service on your behalf for AWS communication?

Comment: @ianmjones : I added the section Additional info about my setup

Comment: I know little about the AWS js library, but your challenge is to wrap your port code with tags so that you get an experience similar to direct http requests. ~Take a look at https://github.com/simonh1000/elm-firebase-demo/blob/master/src/Firebase/fb.js for one way I tackled that

Comment: Thks @SimonH I had something similar in mind ('tagging' the requests and then dispatch the responses based on the tag)... It does the job but I don't find it very elegant and scalable :/ I guess that the ideal solution is to implement AWS Sig v4 in natively Elm anyway...